# React Axios Get Request using Token

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, axios, token, bearer-token

Im trying to get data from my WordPress site that i use as rest api.
when Im sending an axios get request I get error 401.

I got its beacuse the token is null.
Im use this
`let token = localStorage.getItem("token") console.log(token);`
and get null

Comment: Could you explain more, like which token? token that comes from API?

Answer (score 0):

Here in the above code you need to check if there is value available in localStorgae for "token" or not

Try the below code to check the null value first

**First Solution**

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("token") !== null ? localStorage.getItem("token") : "No Token Found";
console.log(token);
```

**Second Solution**

```
let token = '';
if (localStorage.getItem("token") !== null) {
    token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log(token);
}
```